# Can't create linked server from microsoft SQL to Snowflake

Tags: sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, linked-server

Created DNS and installed ODBC Drivers followed same steps from below URL
https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/article/how-to-set-up-a-linked-server-from-sql-server-to-snowflake

Once creating testing connection at last step it shows error like
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SNOWFLAKEDATA" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

But DNS created and used followed same way in URL. Can i know where I made mistake?

Comment: Make sure you've got the DSN in the 64bit ODBC manager.  Also test with a DSN pointing to the local SQL Server.

Comment: I'd make sure it's a System DSN as well as some folks run into issues with User DSNs. The bitness might depend the application, but you can always setup both in the 32-bit ODBC manager and the 64-bit ODBC manager just in case.  You can also test the DSN with another application.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have installed both 64-bit and 32-bit ODBC manager. Still issue is same.

Comment: @SuzyLockwood DNS made for both 64-bit and 32-bit still issue same.

Comment: Pssst. it's a DSN, not a DNS. DNS is completely different

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure to create the linked server to Snowflake with the following information:

- Provider: This should be "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers."
- Data Source: This should match the ODBC system/user DSN name that was previously configured

[image]

- Under the Security Tab on left panel, make sure to add a local login (your local machine's login including your host name) associated to a remote user (snowflake username) and its matching password.

Comment: I have tried same as you mentioned. Same steps mentioned in the question URL also. Still getting same issue. Can help on it?

Comment: Are you able to verify if your DSN is present in the Windows registry? (Start > Run > Regedit). For System DSN, navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE (> Wow6432Node) > ODBC > ODBC.INI and  for user DSN, navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER > SOFTWARE (> Wow6432Node) > ODBC > ODBC.INI