# Can I create a linked server connection to Databricks using SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a SQL Server that currently has a linked server to an Oracle DB.

The Oracle DB is moving to Azure Databricks.

Can I create a linked server from my SQL Server using SSMS to create the connection to AZ Databricks?

Comment: If you can find an ODBC driver that does then you can use that. Keep in mind that Databricks compute needs to be running to use it. Here's the databricks ODBC driver  https://docs.databricks.com/integrations/bi/jdbc-odbc-bi.html

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I edited my question, I think it was not clear. I want to create the linked server to databricks using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio).

Comment: No you were clear. I’ll find you a link to creating an ODBC linked server v

Comment: First install the ODBC driver on the *sql server* and test it. Then follow this https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-configure-a-linked-server-using-the-odbc-driver/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I create a linked server from my SQL Server using SSMS to create the connection to AZ Databricks?

No.  And even if you could, no.  But you can stand up a [Azure Synapse Serverless SQL Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/on-demand-workspace-overview) in front of your Data Lake and create a linked server to that.

> Serverless SQL pool is a query service over the data in your data
> lake. It enables you to access your data through the following
> functionalities:
>
> A familiar T-SQL syntax to query data in place without the need to
> copy or load data into a specialized store. Integrated connectivity
> via the T-SQL interface that offers a wide range of business
> intelligence and ad-hoc querying tools, including the most popular
> drivers. Serverless SQL pool is a distributed data processing system,
> built for large-scale data and computational functions. Serverless SQL
> pool enables you to analyze your Big Data in seconds to minutes,
> depending on the workload. Thanks to built-in query execution
> fault-tolerance, the system provides high reliability and success
> rates even for long-running queries involving large data sets.

Azure Databricks doesn't store data.  The data is stored in the Azure Data Lake, and both Azure Databricks and Synapse Serverless SQL Pool can read the data and serve queries over it.  But to query *through* Databricks requires running a cluster, and there's not a supported driver stack for Linked Server.

Synapse Serverless gives you a normal TDS endpoint and TSQL access to the Data Lake so you can create a linked server to it.  And Serverless supports Delta, Parquet, and CSV, so however your data is stored in the Data Lake clients can query it through the Serverless endpoint.

Comment: I 100% agree that creating a linked server to databricks is a bad idea, But I'm not convinced that it's impossible.

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft how about Snowflake? Based on your answer, seems the same as Databricks applies.

Comment: I found the answer on the Snowflake. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61529033/cant-create-linked-server-from-microsoft-sql-to-snowflake https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/article/how-to-set-up-a-linked-server-from-sql-server-to-snowflake#:~:text=A%20linked%20server%20can%20be,query%20Snowflake%20from%20SQL%20Server.&text=Install%20the%20Snowflake%20ODBC%20driver,Configure%20the%20linked%20server%20provider

Comment: Linked server requires very reliable drivers because it can crash SQL Server.

Comment: Note the snowflake answer is identical to the databricks one: install the ODBC driver then create the linked server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Install the Spark ODBC driver and setup an ODBC connection. This is the same as connecting to Databricks in PowerBI or Tableau. Then in SQL server setup the connection to connect to the ODBC connection previously setup on the server.
I would note in my case the token setup I have is connected to our reporting embedded reporting cluster which is always on. There can be a down time if the cluster has to spin up first so performance would need to be tested based upon needed behavior.
https://www.databricks.com/spark/odbc-drivers-download